# How to calculate the invariant amplitude for a decay process using wick's theorem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, wick-theorem

I have difficulties to apply Wick's theorem to the following problem-set:

> We have three free scalar fields $\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3$. While the field $\phi_3$ has the mass $M$ while $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are massless. With the interaction Hamiltonian:
> $$
> H_{int} = \frac{\lambda_{3333}}{4!}\phi_3^4 + \frac{\lambda_{3111}}{3!}\phi_3\phi_1^3 + \frac{\lambda_{3221}}{2!}\phi_3\phi_2^2\phi_1 + \frac{\lambda_{3211}}{2!}\phi_3\phi_2\phi_1^2 + \space...
> $$
> Now I need to calculate the invariant amplitude for the decay $\phi_3\rightarrow\phi_2\phi_1\phi_1$ by applying Wick's theorem and I only need to keep the dominant terms.

I already calculated it using the series expansion of the Dyson's formula and by solving the integrals. But I think it is way faster using Wick's theorem. (And I'm not sure if I've solved everything correctly either.) I would really appreciate some explanations or tips!